# JavaScript events not working as expected

Tags: javascript

Isn't the JavaScript code here supposed to alert "You have clicked Contact here. I'm not getting the same. Please rectify the errors.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<ul id="nav">
            <li id="click"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var list = document.getElementById("nav");
list.addEventListener("click", function() {
switch(event.target.type.id) {
case "click":
alert("haha");
break;
}, false);
```

Comment: I made a mistake the string is haha that i expected

Comment: Please click "edit" and update the question to what you actually expected. It would also help to state what _does_ happen.

Comment: I believe you want `event.target.id` instead of `event.target.type.id`. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). But that wouldn't "work" either since the clicked element is the link and not the li element. You'd have to traverse up the DOM tree from the clicked element and test whether any ancestor has such an ID, or simply assign the ID to the link.

Comment: no, its just because stack overflow showed my q is full of codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're digging into the wrong thing. `event.target` is the item you're clicking on, `event.type` is the type of event that was triggered:

```
var list = document.getElementById("nav");
list.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case "click":
            alert("haha");
            break;
    }
}, false);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/hSJjK/

**EDIT**: Given you only want `contact` which has an id of `click` to alert, I propose you try this instead:

```
var list = document.getElementById("click");
list.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    alert("haha");
}, false);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/hSJjK/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: The element also has id "click".

Comment: @dystroy ahh, I missed that. If he's going to go to the effort of decorating it with an id then it makes more sense to attach the event handler to the id, no?

Comment: it's shpowing alert for all the li elements. i just want the same for contact.:-(

Comment: @user2899508 did you click on the fiddle and try it...?

Comment: @user2899508 then why not bind to the id of the contact li? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/hSJjK/1/

Comment: yes, but it's displaying the id for every other li elements as well.

Comment: @user2899508 not a problem. If this answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Don't you want to adjust your answer then?

Comment: there's a problem dudes.

Comment: doesn't his cause event delegation, means i'm supposed to assign separate event handlers for all of the clickable elements. this may cause an incredibly long section of code that simply attached event handlers.

Comment: @user2899508 yes.. that is why we have jQuery.. ._.